# Flow type - Index signature declaring the expected key / value type is missing in GenericType

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm having issues to access a object property dynamically with a Generic Type . Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function useForm<FormValues>(initialValues: FormValues) {
    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState<FormValues>(initialValues)

    function getValue(fieldName: string) {
        return formValues[fieldName]
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

> 7:        return formValues[fieldName]
>                             ^ Cannot get `formValues[fieldName]` because an index signature declaring the expected key / value type is missing
>   in `FormValues` [1]. References: 4:   const [formValues, setFormValues]
>   = useState(initialValues)
>                                                    ^ [1]

Here is the Try Flow link:
https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAORSoYsBQXd+AdhmAR+BYgDFoIADySoIAGooANviSEAfAApg-YDGAqlq9QC44cxSrWEAlLi4BINCMLwA2nSnGb2YjEsfdQBdOABeMVJySllva3VtXX1DZSC7LjhMuAysvkEDETgAcyQYIK06YCRlABMAORQQJHM3KF0i+xwczMd2GHwoUS95NM8q2oam4O6aLmogA

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets simplify the question:

I. `useState`have the following type:

```
export function useState<S>(
  initialState: (() => S) | S,
): [S, Dispatch<BasicStateAction<S>>] {}
```

II. For us is important returned type:

```
export function simpleUseState<S>(initialState: S): [S] {}
```

III. Simplified version:

```
declare var simpleUseState: <S>(initialState: S)=> [S];

function useForm<FormValues>(initialValues: FormValues, fieldName: string) {
    const [formValues] = simpleUseState<FormValues>(initialValues)

    return formValues[fieldName];
}
```

And we have [the same error](https://flow.org/try/#0AQ4EwUwYwGwQwE4WAN0cAzgSwLYAcYIBVDCAZQBc4KIAuYAHjID4AKLAOywqzhkup1gZAJQBeZsADaZALoBuAFChgy0ADMArhyg8A9h2CbSAMT0IcDMxYBqfTRAxtO3XjDswHGetZwevADTA6lgQMGAAcnA4QhgUCJwA5iLAAN5qKiBQBnHS6uZ+9o6ywGKYuATEpAI0VgX+js5cPHwNGCIZmYoAkN1IFJoIHN35tkUYUiFhkdEQCp0AvkA)

Because a Generic type has no  key/value signature, for example it can be a `number` or `null` - we need to add [constraints](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-generic-types-act-as-bounds) on Generic:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function useForm<FormValues: {[string]: string}>(initialValues: FormValues) {
//                         ^ constraint
    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState<FormValues>(initialValues)

    function getValue(fieldName: string) {
        return formValues[fieldName]
    }
}
```